# get order issue in observer in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to get last order id in observer after place order. My code like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AfterOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $orderFacory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderFacory = $orderFacory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        echo $this->orderFacory->getOrderId(); exit;
    }
}
```

But I cannot get last order id.

Comment: Which event you used?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get last order id from event like this:

```
$orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
$lastorderId = $orderIds[0];

echo $lastorderId; exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to order information like this.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AfterOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $orderFacory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderFacory = $orderFacory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        echo $order->getId();
        exit;
    }
}
```